# Напечатать строки в порядке убывания

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список строк. В каждой строке есть числа, нужно отображать строки в зависимости от количества цифр в числе. От строки с наибольшим количеством цифр до строки с наименьшим.

```
array = ["My name 1 - Andrew", "My 2222 surname - Ivanov", "I am 25 "]
string = ", ".join(array)
string = string.split()
for i in string:
    if i.isdigit():
        pass
```

Comment: А что, если в строке 2 числа? Считать общее количество цифр в них или наибольшее из двух?

Answer (score 2):

может, воспользоваться регулярками? тут выбирается самое длинное число, если их несколько

```
import re 

a = [x[1] for x in sorted(zip(map(lambda x: max(map(len, re.findall(r'\d+', x))), array), array), reverse=True)]
print(a)

# ['My 2222 surname - Ivanov', 'I am 25 ', 'My name 1 - Andrew']
```